# Iterate over function and concatinate results

Tags: python, pandas, loops, concatenation

So let's say I have a function x which I want to iterate over a list of 3
What I wat to do is to iterate over this list and concatinate the results.
Like this:

```
number1 = func(1)
number2 = func(2)
number3 = func(3)
```

And then

```
Results = pd.concat([number1, number2, number3], axis = 1)
```

I tried it like this

```
numbers = list(range(1:3)
for i in numbers:
  Results = pd.concat([func(i)], axis = 1)
```

it didn't work...

Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use list-comprehension and loops like the other answers suggested, or, if `func` takes only one parameter, you could use `map`:

```
df = pd.concat(map(func, range(1, 4)), axis=1)
```

Example output:

```
>>> def func(x):
...    return pd.DataFrame({f'col{x}':[x, x, x]},)
    
>>> df = pd.concat(map(func, range(1, 4)), axis=1)
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using list comprehension:

```py
results = pd.concat([func(i) for i in range(1,4)], axis=1)
```

or with a conventional loop:

```py
lst = []
for i in range(1,4):
    lst.append(func(i))
results = pd.concat(lst, axis=1)
```

This will loop and concatenate `func(1)`, `func(2)`, and `func(3)`.  It's important to remember `range(a,b)` gives the range `[a,b)` where `b` is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension:

```py
numbers = list(range(1,4))
Results = pd.concat([func(i) for i in numbers], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Only problem is that I'm getting a 'diagonal' DF with i columns

Comment: what is your `func` function returning?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways to do it. The first uses a loop as you have hinted at in your question. The second simply uses a list comprehension to call the function repeatedly and use the results to initialize your Results dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
def func(i):
    return i / 2
numbers = list(range(1, 4))
Results = pd.DataFrame({'result':[func(i) for i in numbers]})
print('Using list comprehension:')
print(Results)

Results = pd.DataFrame({'result':[]})
for i in numbers:
    Results = pd.concat([Results, pd.DataFrame({'result':[func(i)]})], axis=0)
print('Using concat in a loop:')
print(Results)
```

Output:

```
Using list comprehension:
   result
0     0.5
1     1.0
2     1.5
Using concat in a loop:
   result
0     0.5
0     1.0
0     1.5
```